# type inference in OCaml says my function is 'a list list -> list while it should be 'a list

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml, type-inference

I am new to OCaml and have very little experience with functional programming.
I have written the following function

```ml
let rec reverse l =
  match l with
  | [] -> []
  | h::rest -> (reverse rest) @ h
```

which is supposed to reverse the elements in a list, transforming `[1;2;3]` into `[3;2;1]` for instance.
I don't know if the function will work but the issue is that OCaml infers that function to be of type `'a list list -> 'a list` while I'd expect it to be an `'a list -> 'a list`.

```
# reverse [1;2;3;4];;
Error: This expression has type int but an expression was expected of type 'a list
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The concatenation operator `@` expects both its operands to be lists.

When you write  `(reverse rest) @ h`, it is immediately inferred that `h` must be a list. Since `l = h::rest` and `h` is a list, then `l` must be a list of lists.

Instead, try to replace `(reverse rest) @ h` with `(reverse rest) @ [h]`. This should work correctly.

However, note that the concatenation `a @ b` takes time linear in the length of `a`. Since you call this concatenation repeatedly, the overall complexity of your algorithm is quadratic. That's very slow. It is actually possible to reverse a list in linear time if you use an accumulator to build the reversed list progressively, using only `::` and never `@`.

Comment: thank you ! right now I'm not really caring about performance since I'm just learning a whole new way of programming but I appreciate your help. I will sure try to make a linear time version later!

Answer (score 4):

The OCaml typechecker always infers the best possible type for an implementation ((outside of advanced features like GADTs, higher-rank polymorphism and first class modules)).

Thus, if the inferred type of a function does not match your expectation, it means that there is an error in your implementation.

Here, the issue is that the type of `(@)` is `'a list -> 'a list -> 'a list`. Thus `reverse rest @ h` implies that:

- `h` is a list (thus `l` is a list of list of some element `'b`).
- `reverse rest` as the same type as `h`

Consequently, the type of `reverse` is `'b list list -> 'b list`.